# Error 504 intermitente utilizando api gateway de AWS

Tags: aws, nginx, timeout

Estoy utilizando el api gateway de AWS y me estoy encontrando con el siguiente problema

Cuando ataco desde un navegador mediante una URL a la api que tenemos directamente sin pasar por el api gateway no obtengo ningún problema y los códigos de respuesta son siempre 200.

Atacando a través del api gateway me devuelve errores 504 de timeout intermitentes cuando la petición excede de 10 segundos.

Desde el api gateway puedo hacer 10000 peticiones por segundo y el tiempo de espera predeterminado es superior a 30.

En nginx tengo añadido los siguientes parámetros:
keepalive_timeout 10m;
proxy_connect_timeout  600s;

¿Alguien se ha encontrado con algo parecido?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow** , te recomiendo que realices el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y asi obtengas tu primera medalla, ademas mira [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para así poder ayudarte mejor con tu pregunta.

Comment: La pregunta está mal redactada. ... para ti todo es api gateway ... ¿no será que tienes que reemplazar algún uso (en la pregunta) por el de _Lambda_?

Comment: No utilizo Lambda de AWS si es a eso lo que te refieres. Lo único que tengo es un api gateway configurado para atacar a dos endpoints, uno de ellos para obtener un token de autenticación y otro para realizar un get. Desde un fichero php ataco a la URL que generan estos dos endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Han resuelto la casuística.

El problema se debía a que el security group del api gateway no estaba apuntando a las ips correctas.

Muchas gracias